# How can I change date string to POSIXct format?

Tags: r

I am trying to convert these dates in created_at column to the number of seconds column created_at_dt using POSIXct.

```
created_at
<chr>
Fri May 26 17:30:01 +0000 2017              
Fri May 26 17:30:05 +0000 2017              
Fri May 26 17:30:05 +0000 2017              
Fri May 26 17:30:04 +0000 2017              
Fri May 26 17:30:12 +0000 2017
```

Example of what i want to achieve:

```
created_at_dt
<dbl>
1495819801              
1495819805              
1495819805              
1495819804              
1495819812
```

I tried the following line but got only NA values introduced.

```
tweets <- tweets %>% 
   mutate(created_at_dt = asPOSIXct(as.numeric('created_at')))
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to specify the [correct format string](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) for `as.POSIXct`.

Also, `created_at` should not be in quotes for `mutate()`.

```
library(dplyr)

tweets <- tweets %>% 
  mutate(created_at_dt = as.POSIXct(created_at, 
                                    format = "%a %B %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y") %>%
                                      as.numeric())
```

Result:

```
                      created_at created_at_dt
1 Fri May 26 17:30:01 +0000 2017    1495819801
2 Fri May 26 17:30:05 +0000 2017    1495819805
3 Fri May 26 17:30:05 +0000 2017    1495819805
4 Fri May 26 17:30:04 +0000 2017    1495819804
5 Fri May 26 17:30:12 +0000 2017    1495819812
```

The data:

```
tweets <- structure(list(created_at = c("Fri May 26 17:30:01 +0000 2017", 
"Fri May 26 17:30:05 +0000 2017", "Fri May 26 17:30:05 +0000 2017", 
"Fri May 26 17:30:04 +0000 2017", "Fri May 26 17:30:12 +0000 2017"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```